# Python TypeError why is a list being treated as a function (QuickSort example)

Tags: python

First question!  So I'm trying to learn Python (coming from two semesters of Java usage) and I've come across a TypeError I believe is due to a having a function when there should be a list.  Here's my code that *works*:

```
t = [3,5,2,4,1]

def quicksort(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return []
    pivot = [lst[0]]
    left = [x for x in lst if x < pivot[0]]
    right = [x for x in lst if x > pivot[0]]
    ans = quicksort(left) + pivot + quicksort(right)
    return ans
    #return quicksort(left) + pivot + quicksort[right]

print quicksort(t)
```

That worked.  But when I did:

```
t = [3,5,2,4,1]

def quicksort(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return []
    pivot = [lst[0]]
    left = [x for x in lst if x < pivot[0]]
    right = [x for x in lst if x > pivot[0]]
    #ans = quicksort(left) + pivot + quicksort(right)
    #return ans
    return quicksort(left) + pivot + quicksort[right]

print quicksort(t)
```

I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickSortTest.py", line 13, in <module>
    print quicksort(t)
  File "quickSortTest.py", line 11, in quicksort
    return quicksort(left) + pivot + quicksort[right]
  File "quickSortTest.py", line 11, in quicksort
    return quicksort(left) + pivot + quicksort[right]
  File "quickSortTest.py", line 11, in quicksort
    return quicksort(left) + pivot + quicksort[right]
TypeError: 'function' object is unsubscriptable
```

I would like to understand the difference and would very much appreciate an explanation!

-S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
quicksort[right]
```

You used brackets instead of parentheses here. Brackets are for indexing and slicing; parentheses are for function calls.